# win10/CREATE EXTENSION Pgrouting--could not access file "$libdir/libpgrouting-2.3"

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, installation

My system version is win10 10.0.14393.

I install the binaries-win64 into my C:/PostgreSQL/pg96.

At the end of the installing, there is a Warning "could not create database file "$libdir/libpgrouting-2.3": No such file or directory".

I tried to use psql to install using "CREATE EXTENSION Pgrouting", I got the same bad return: "could not access file "$libdir/libpgrouting-2.3": No such file or directory".

How do I deal with this problem.

Comment: I have the file libpgrouting-2.3.dll in my pg96/lib folder

Comment: And I have added the environment variable in my PATH.    C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\lib;  C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like you are using the BigSQL distribution.  Do not use the installers for that since the PostgreSQL folder layout of BigSQL is different from PostgreSQL EDB distribution (which is what the installers are designed to work with).  Use the binaries instead - http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/

The binaries also assume PostgreSQL EDB layout folder structure, so for BigSQL, you'll want to copy these into separate folders instead of the folder paths in the binaries.

Put and copy the files in right location as I described:

http://postgis.us/Presentations/postgis_install_guide_23.html#/windows

Instructions excerpted from above link

> BigSQL does not include pgRouting yet, but for windows you can use the zip files from - http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/ to get pgRouting. Make sure to use the zip files (not the installer) (and change the path where you copy **share** folder contents to **pg96/share/postgresql**, copy **lib** folder contents to **pg96/lib/postgresql** folder, **bin** folder contents pg96/bin).
>
> You'll also need the libstdc++-6.dll which you can find in the osm2pgrouting zip files in the extra_deps folder. Copy this to pg96/bin.